# Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp, model-view-controller

I was try many combination many and more than many - try to use ModelAndView and return mav and try model.addAttribute and return String, and write in jsp page - auto select and customerGet and try customerPost, but not any one combination help me at all.

How can I correct the code? I need to have only one WORKING example to understand how send code from controller to jsp, cant find any working example about it - because they dont work with my mvc+jsp

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Customer implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "address_id")
private Address address;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private User user;



@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "address")
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Address implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

private String country;
private String city;
private String street;
private String flat;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "address")
private Customer customer;


@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "email")
public class User implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

private String email;
private String password;
private boolean enable;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "user")
private Customer customer;
```

my bad code

```
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping(value = "index")
    public class HomeController {

        @Autowired
        private CustomerService customerService;


    //    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    //    public ModelAndView  getRegistrationForm() {
    //        Customer customer = new Customer();
    //        User user = new User();
    //        Address address = new Address();
    //        customer.setAddress(address);
    //        customer.setUser(user);
    //        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    //        modelAndView.addObject("customer", customer);
    ////        model.addAttribute("customer", new Customer());
    //        modelAndView.setViewName("customer");
    //        return modelAndView;
    ////        return new ModelAndView("register", "customer", customer);
    ////        return "index";
    //    }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String customer(Model model) {
    //            ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    //        Customer customer = new Customer();
    //        User user = new User();
    //        Address address = new Address();
    //        customer.setAddress(address);
    //        customer.setUser(user);
    //        model.addAttribute(user);
    //        model.addAttribute(address);
    //        model.addAttribute("customer", customer);
                    model.addAttribute("customerGet", new Customer());
                return "index";
        }

    //        return new ModelAndView("customer", "command", customer);
    //    }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/addCustomer", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String registerCustomer(@Valid @ModelAttribute(value = "customerPost") Customer customer, Model model,
                                       BindingResult result) {
            if (result.hasErrors())
                return "index";
            customerService.createCustomer(customer);
            model.addAttribute("registrationSuccess", "Registered Successfully.");
            return "index";
        }

    //    @RequestMapping(value = "/addCustomer", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    //    public String registerCustomer
    //            (@ModelAttribute("customer") Customer customer, Model model,
    //             BindingResult result) {
    //        if (result.hasErrors()) return "register";
    //        customerService.createCustomer(customer);
    //        model.addAttribute("registrationSuccess", "Registered Successfully.");
    //        return "redirect:/index";
    //    }
     // @RequestMapping(value = "/addCustomer", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    //    public String addStudent(@ModelAttribute("customer")Customer customer,
    //                             ModelMap model) {
    //        model.addAttribute("firstName", customer.getFirstName());
    //        model.addAttribute("lastName", customer.getLastName());
    //        model.addAttribute("country", customer.getAddress().getCountry());
    //        model.addAttribute("city", customer.getAddress().getCity());
    //        model.addAttribute("street", customer.getAddress().getStreet());
    //        model.addAttribute("flat", customer.getAddress().getFlat());
    //        model.addAttribute("email", customer.getUser().getEmail());
    //        model.addAttribute("password", customer.getUser().getPassword());
    //        customerService.createCustomer(customer);
    //        return "index";
    //    }
        }
```

my application.properties  spring-boot

spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/pages/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

mybad jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<c:url var="addAction" value="/index/addCustomer" ></c:url>

<spring:form action="${addAction}" modelAttribute="customerGet">
    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Create Student</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
      <tr>
          <td>
<%--          <spring:input path="id" readonly="true" size="8"  disabled="true" />--%>
              <spring:hidden path="id" />
          </td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>first name</td>
            <td><spring:input path="firstName"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>last name</td>
            <td><spring:input path="lastName"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>country</td>
            <td><spring:input path="address.country"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>city</td>
            <td><spring:input path="address.city"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>street</td>
            <td><spring:input path="address.street"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>flat</td>
            <td><spring:input path="address.flat"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>email</td>
            <td><spring:input path="user.email"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>password</td>
            <td><spring:input path="user.password"/></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <spring:button>add customer</spring:button>
</spring:form>

</body>

</html>
```

i find page at http://localhost:8081/index/index
and again HAVE BUG after complite form and select button
i automaticle redirect to page
in http://localhost:8081/index/addCustomer

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Thu Oct 24 16:14:59 UTC 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'customerGet' available as request attribute
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'customerGet' available as request attribute
```

also when i see mysql base - i find my entity - and i have second question = how to correct create new customer - only new in get methot controller or in methot need write so this line ?  use hibernate-jpa - crud repository

```
   Customer customer = new Customer();
   User user = new User();
   Address address = new Address();
   customer.setAddress(address);
   customer.setUser(user);
```

Comment: What happens when you try to load the page?  What URL are you trying to hit? The way you have it mapped in the controller the `customer` method would be at `/index/index`, is that what you are hitting?

Comment: ooo... i see form in http://localhost:8081/index/index

Comment: but i want to see it in  localhost:8081/index and after add object dont leave page, page must be reload

Comment: after i complite form a have error, put it at end my main post

Comment: i again have error - in every url such as localhost:8081/index/index  localhost:8081/index localhost:8081/index/addCustomer    whats wrong??????

Comment: What error are you seeing?  Also, if you want the page available at `locahost:8081/index` instead of `localhost:8081/index/index`, you can change the request mapping on the `customer` method to `@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)`. All methods on your controller are already mapped to `/index` because of the `@RequestMapping("index")` you have on the class.

Answer (score 0):

BindingResult error is raised when you expect an object in the view, but it is not added in the model. (in your case : "customerGet")
A short analysis of your code, you have :

```
<spring:form action="${addAction}" modelAttribute="customerGet">
```

=> you must have model.addAttribute("customerGet", new Customer()) in all the controller methods that return this view.
The index view is returned in 2 cases:

1. GET /index/index => we have it here, all good
2. POST /index/addCustomer => you **don't** have it here, it will fail with binding result.

Comment: but i need this? in get method

Comment: Customer customer = new Customer();
   User user = new User();
   Address address = new Address();
   customer.setAddress(address);
   customer.setUser(user);

Comment: Yes, you need to have model.addAttribute("customerGet",.. )  in both GET and POST methods. Usually in view you will never return the entities directly because of the bidirectional relationship.

Comment: If you have user.email => Customer must have a non null User object otherwise it will fail, so you must add a customer object with non-null user, address objects.

Comment: i see this code and try do do it. how i can do it?
@RequestMapping(value = "/customer/registration")
 public ModelAndView getRegistrationForm() {
  Customer customer = new Customer();
  User user = new User();
  BillingAddress ba = new BillingAddress();
  ShippingAddress sa = new ShippingAddress();
  customer.setShippingAddress(sa);
  customer.setBillingAddress(ba);
  customer.setUsers(user);

  return new ModelAndView("register", "customer", customer);
 }

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the `BindingResult` error because you're not returning the `CustomerGet` object that you placed in the model and view, by just returning the String "index" you are just sending the user to `index.jsp` without the model attribute to populate the form.  Your customer method needs to return a `ModelAndView` object from your `customer` method. If you change your `customer` method to look like this it should work:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public ModelAndView customer(Model model) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("index");
    Customer customer = new Customer();
    customer.setAddress(new Address());
    customer.setUser(new User());
    model.addAttribute("customerGet", customer);

    return modelAndView;
}
```

This creates a `ModelAndView` object specifying "index" as the jsp page for the view, then populates a new customer object with a user and an address and puts it on the model and view.  To actually see the for populated with values you'll obviously have to set values on the Customer object's attributes for things like firstName, lastName, etc. Note that I changed the `@RequestMapping` on the method to "/" so that the page would be available at `localhost:8081/index` instead of `localhost:8081/index/index`.